# The method run() is not running when i start a thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

i have a class who extends from Thread:

```
public class Generador extends Thread {

...

public Generador(int marca, float sleep) {

    this.marca = marca;
    this.sleep = sleep;
    this.cantActivaciones = 0;
}

@Override
public void start() {
    marcadorAct++;
    cantActivaciones++;
    if (marcadorAct == 3) {
        desalojarPasajero = true;
        marcadorAct = 0;
    } else {
        desalojarPasajero = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("The thread is running.....");
}
```

My problem is that the method run() is not working when i use the start() method. Here is my code:

```
public class Simulación {

...
Generador generador[] = new Generador[30]; // Arr of threads...

public Simulación() {   // The constructor
    ....
    for (int i = 0; i < generador.length; i++) {
        generador[i] = new Generador((i + 1) * 1000000, rand.nextInt(3) + rand.nextFloat());
    }
    ....
}

public void generarPasajero() { // The method who decides to start a thread...

    for (int i = 0; i < generador.length; i++) {
            if (!generador[i].isAlive()) {
                generador[i].start();   // HERE START DOESNT RUN THE RUN() METHOD
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

I hope you could understand my problem..
Anyone can help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Try to put `super.Start()` as last statement in your class's `Start()` method.

Comment: You should not override `start`, instead put your logic in `run`

Comment: `super.start()`, lowercase, but yes, was just about to type that. :)

Comment: The run() is working now, but i get the error  java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException in specifically in the line super.start()

Comment: if you get IllegalThreadStateException that means you started the thread twice. like others said, do not override start, it is an even better idea to never subclass Thread, make Runnables or Callables instead.

Comment: I am not overriding start now, and i am using the condition .isAlive() before starting a new thread, so i dont what can be happening :(

Comment: Re, "I am not overriding start now,..." That sounds like it's time for you to ask a new question, and show your new code. _This_ question has been answered (the answer to this one was, you were never starting the thread because the `start()` that your code called was an override.)

Comment: Well, thanks. I will do it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By overriding the `start()` method, you prevent what the method would have done on it own, because you replaced the code it executes. That means it won't start a thread by running the `run()` method.

[This page from Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-thread-class-start-method/) explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to move all your code to the `run` function. The `start` function from the `Thread` class is overridden in your implementation.

Additionally, your class would be a valid `Runnable` class. If the task need to be started without starting a new thread, the `run()` function can be called.